# Python binary float to integer conversion using ctypes

Tags: python, floating-point, type-conversion, ctypes

Please help me to understand this code snippet:

```
def binary_float_to_int(float_number: float) -> int:

    return ctypes.c_uint.from_buffer(ctypes.c_float(float_number)).value
```

The results from these inputs:

```
print(binary_float_to_int(7.1746481e-43)) 
print(binary_float_to_int(5.3809861e-43))
```

Are: `512 & 384`

Why does the simple Python conversion `int(7.1746481e-43)` not work?
Are there any other ways to do this type of conversion?

Comment: `int(7.1746481e-43)` works fine so far as I can see. [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) rounds towards zero, and `7.1746481e-43` is less than 1. I'm not sure what `binary_float_to_int()` is doing, but `7.1746481e-43` isn't anywhere close to `512`.

Comment: @brunns the conversion is the 32-bit integer value of the 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point value representing that floating point number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ctypes` code is:

1. Put the floating point number in a 32-bit C (IEEE 754-format) `ctypes.c_float(float_number)`
2. Treat that same 4-byte value, as an C unsigned int. `ctypes.c_uint.from_buffer()`
3. Extract that unsigned integer value `.value`

Your numbers are correct, if you want the raw 32-bit value of those floating point numbers expressed as integers.  Here's another way to do it:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('i',struct.pack('f',7.1746481e-43))[0]
512
>>> struct.unpack('i',struct.pack('f',5.3809861e-43))[0]
384
```

These generate the 4-byte float32 value, then unpack it as an integer.

`7.1746481e-43` is a very small value close to zero.  `int()` returns the integer portion...in this case, zero, so that's as expected as well.